# HTTP Live Streaming proxy setup

Tags: http-live-streaming, http-proxy, envoyproxy

I'm currently deciding on what route to take for setting up load balancing and scaling for HLS.

My intuition is to have a custom component (that will auto-scale) and load-balance to it using sticky balancing based on the stream ID.

So basically one of two things can happen:

- there is a proxy with the stream that is not overloaded (that one will be used)
- all proxies with the stream are overloaded, the least used proxy will be used that will fetch the stream from the source

There can be extra layers on top of this with topology awareness, but this is the basic stuff.

However, I was told that the idea behind HLS was that you can just use normal HTTP proxies, which is however an area I'm not familiar with.

Is it possible to configure an HTTP proxy in this content-aware way? If yes, how would I go about it?

I'm really only familiar with setting up generic pools of proxies without additional configuration.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/warren-bank/HLS-Proxy

I am not familiar with this area, but I would think a special purposed proxy like above works better and may save you some headache.

Answer (score 0):

[haproxy.org](https://www.haproxy.org/) *(open source)* and [haproxy.com](https://www.haproxy.com/) *(commercial)* can support streaming applications.

See [extending HAProxy with the stream processing offload engine](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/extending-haproxy-with-the-stream-processing-offload-engine) and [the Digital Ocean's High-Availability HAProxy Setup](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-high-availability-haproxy-setup-with-corosync-pacemaker-and-floating-ips-on-ubuntu-14-04)